# Map system resource dynamically to requested uri in apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I have file whose name is not consistent but uri to access that file is constant. How can I map the file to requested uri dynamicallyin apache?
Ex: I have file test.xml and uri is https://example.com/test.xml. And I can map this easily. But if test.xml in server is going to change to temp.xml or user.xml etc, then how to map given constant uri to dynamically changing file resource name.
But it is sure that, directory containing this file will have only one xml file.

Comment: Do you have some rule about the files that must be changed? Perhaps all xml files? What files will be mapped and what files won't be changed?

Comment: No such rules. I have one single xml file in a directory which needs to served whenver client makes https://example.com/test.xml request. I am able to serve that file when file name is test.xml. But when file name changes, I am not able to map resource part of uri(i.e. test.xml in uri) to file name present in system. In other words, requirement is like, I need to serve one xml file in a particular directory irrespective of its name whenever the client makes https://example.com/test.xml request.